# How to recover the permission of an invisible source control folder for TFS admin

Tags: tfs

Our TFS admin accidentally removed the permission of herself for a source control folder, as a result she cannot see the folder in Visual Studio any more.

How could she do anything to recover the permission of that folder?

It's TFS 2010, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update 10/17:

- The admin is already in the Project Administrators group, and actually she just removed the group instead of her personal account from the security page.
- Before she removed herself, she also unclicked the "inherit security settings" in the security page.
- Now there is no user/group has the management permission of that folder, only some normal user has the Read permission.

Comment: Any ProjectAdministrator should be able to recover the folder, since these have inherited "Manage Permissions" roles. A Server Admin and Project Collection Administrator may need to add themselves to the Project Admin group first.

Comment: Before our admin removed herself, she also unclicked the "inherit security setting", so that won't work either?

Comment: Have you tried add the user to any other groups which have access to that folder like "Contributors" and "Build Administrators"?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT All the groups have been removed from the Security page, so that won't work either? There is only one user is listed, which has only the Read permission.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your account in **ProjectName\Project Administrators** group.

Members of this group can administer all aspects of the team project, then you just need to reset the permissions back to the defaults.

As for unclicked the "inherit security setting", it doesn't matter. This is used for such as: Allow “Read” access to the “Team Project”. Next, on the “Project” folder, uncheck “Inherit security settings” and add that account with Deny for “Read”. You also had to re-add all of the default groups since they were no longer inherited from the Team Project. After this setting the user should allow access to a child folder without allowing access to the parent folder.

More details about **Inheritance**, please take a look at this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx#Inherit) from MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, and what if the "Project Administrators" has been removed also from the security page after unclicking the "inherit security settings"?

Comment: Did you have any other project Administrator account? Using that account to change the permission set by your TFS Admin. Or you can also try to use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) . For example: `tf permission /user:userID /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection` which will return the modified permission for that user under the collection path. Also work with server path.

Comment: Just tried the tf permission command, didn't work either, and the command would prompt something like "The item $/PATH_TO_THE_INVISIBLE_FOLDER does not exist at the specified version, or you do not have permission to access it".

Comment: This is not used for her(your TFS Admin), it's used for the other team project administrator. Did you have any other team project Administrator? Or you can use the TFS Admin account to add your account to team project Administrator. Then you will have enough permission to change the folder's  permission setting for your TFS Admin account.

Comment: Still don't understand. Our admin is already in that project administrator group and it's the group that was removed from the security configuration page, so if she can't see the path, other admin should be the same? BTW, updated the question again, sorry for the unclear description before.